# Laravel 4 eloquent

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

Is there any way I can do this with eloquent?

```
$orders = Customer::with('orders','orders.shop')->where('orders.shop.location','=','Japan')->get()
```

Customers, orders and shop are tables where 1 customer has many orders and each order has one shop only.

Location is a column in the shop table

I keep getting an error stating orders.shop.location is a column not found.

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set relationships in your models?

Answer (score 2):

You need to defined relationship in your model classes.

Customer model:

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Order');
}
```

Order model:

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Customer');
}
```

Then if you want orders of a special customer you just have to do :

```
$orders = Customer::find($id)->orders;
```

Or find the user attatched to an order:

```
$user = Order::find($id)->user;
```

You can also use the same kind of relation between your Shop and Order model and do something like this:

```
$orders = Order::with(array('shop' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('location', '=', 'japan');

}))->get();
```

Which should give you all orders for a shop located in japan.

More informations about this type of request:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Answer (score 1):

in CostumerModel you need set a relationship (One To Many):

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->hasMany('OrderModel', 'foreign_key_in_orderTable');
}
```

in OrderModel too:

```
public function costumer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('CostumerModel', 'foreign_key_in_orderTable');
}
```

then in OrderModel one more relationship with Shop (One To One):

```
public function shop()
{
    return $this->hasOne('ShopModel', 'foreign_key');
}
```

Now in ShopModel (One To One):

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('OrderModel', 'local_key');
}
```

query:

```
$orders = Customer::with('costumer', 'shop')->where('location','=','Japan')->get();
```